How to hide a field in hybris backoffice when it is null
Is it possible to hide a field in hybris backoffice for PromotionSourceRule.
We have a custom field link, it is localized and now I want to show only fields with some value and hide empty fields. It is not dynamic form .
On an image attached I would like to show only field with "nl" language. 
